# Set JSON object value from Dropdown and text input

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have this dropdown in my HTML next to a text box and a button.

What I want to happen is the user selects something from the dropdown. Then they input a number in the box. When they click save, it takes that number, and assigns it to the coordinating location in the JSON object for the item they selected from the drop down.

Here is kind of what I have so far. The commented out line is what I want to happen at that spot. Not sure how to code it.

https://jsfiddle.net/tq4xL0xs/

```js
var userIngredients = {
    Acorn:0,
    Apple:0,
    Armoranth:0,
    BigHeartyRaddish:0};
    
    
    function setUserAmountToVariables()
{

    var tempNumber =  document.getElementById("itemInput").value;

    var tempItem = document.getElementById("dimeADozen");


//set tempnumber to whatever the user selected as the item from the dropdown (in useringredients object)

}
```

```html
<select id="dimeADozen">
    <option data-value="userIngredients.Acorn">Acorn</option>
    <option value=userIngredients.Apple>Apple</option>
    <option value=userIngredients.Armoranth>Armoranth</option>
    <option value=userIngredients.BigHeartyRaddish>Big Hearty Raddish</option>  
</select>
<input type="number" id="itemInput" min="0" max="99999">
<button onclick="setUserAmountToVariables();">Save Ingredient</button>
```

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: what more do you want me to explain? 

See the JSON object? the value of the keys are all set to 0. 

When the user inputs a number into the box, and they select an item from the drop down and then click save. 

I want the selection from the drop down to find the coordinating key in the object, then use the number from the text box to set the value.

Comment: can you see my answer

Comment: @Lauren Townsend cool. we cannot do what you are asking with the current JSON object. We actually need a identity for the object. So can we change that json object into JSON array?

Comment: how can it work with a JSON array?

Comment: with the ref id we can change json easily.
var userIngredients = [{
    Name:"Acorn", "qty":0, "id":1},
   { Name:"Apple", "qty":0, "id":2},
{ Name:"Armoranth", "qty":0, "id":3},
{ Name:"BigHeartyRaddish", "qty":0, "id":4}];

Comment: I think this is what you want; userIngredients["Apple"] = 23;

Comment: so if that array is used instead of the object I had, how can it work?

Comment: your button click event is not working. Otherwise this will work. https://jsfiddle.net/tq4xL0xs/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `userIngredients.Acorn` as the value in your options instead just use the keys of the JSON object like just `Acorn` will be enough.

```js
var userIngredients = {
    Acorn:0,
    Apple:0,
    Armoranth:0,
    BigHeartyRaddish:0};
    
    
    function setUserAmountToVariables()
{

    var tempNumber =  document.getElementById("itemInput").value;

    var tempItem = document.getElementById("dimeADozen").value;
    userIngredients[tempItem] = tempNumber;
    console.log(userIngredients);
}
```

```html
<select id="dimeADozen">
    <option value="Acorn">Acorn</option>
    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
    <option value="Armoranth">Armoranth</option>
    <option value="BigHeartyRaddish">Big Hearty Raddish</option>  
</select>
<input type="number" id="itemInput" min="0" max="99999">
<button onclick="setUserAmountToVariables();">Save Ingredient</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 
`Object.assign(UserIngredient,{Nameofitem:tempNumber})`
replace the name of item with item in object

Comment: but what if it changes. what if the user selects Acorn from the drop down and inputs a number 2. I want to be able to change the location of the key:value pair based on what is selected in the drop down

Comment: what do you mean by change the location

Comment: ok, for example. The user selects Apple from the drop down, and inputs 5 in the box. Then they click save.

userIngredients.Apple is now set to 5 instead of 0.

Then the user wants to save acorns. So they select Acorn from the dropdown, type in 10 in the box and click save.

userIngredients.Acorn is now set to 10 instead of 0

Comment: what do you want then

Comment: i've said what I want multiple times. you apparently aren't understanding

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to change `data-value` to `value` of first option item . Because we need to retrieve the selected option by `.value`.

```js
var userIngredients = {
    Acorn:0,
    Apple:0,
    Armoranth:0,
    BigHeartyRaddish:0};
    
    
    function setUserAmountToVariables()
{

    var tempNumber =  document.getElementById("itemInput").value;

    var tempItem = document.getElementById("dimeADozen").value;    
    tempItem = tempItem.split(".")[1];
    userIngredients[tempItem] = tempNumber;
    console.log(userIngredients);
}
```

```html
<select id="dimeADozen">
    <option value="userIngredients.Acorn">Acorn</option>
    <option value=userIngredients.Apple>Apple</option>
    <option value=userIngredients.Armoranth>Armoranth</option>
    <option value=userIngredients.BigHeartyRaddish>Big Hearty Raddish</option>  
</select>
<input type="number" id="itemInput" min="0" max="99999">
<button onclick="setUserAmountToVariables();">Save Ingredient</button>
```